# Regex to disallow HTML tags?

Tags: html, regex

I'm in need of a regular expression that would allow anything except for HTML tags.  The trick here is that < and > characters *would* be allowed, but just not with text between them (but other characters are fine).

**The following *would* be allowed:**

```
hello world
!@$%^&*()_+'":;[]{}()\|#
<<<<<<<
>>>>>
<>
><
<087>
<-->
```

**The following *would not* be allowed**

```
<html>
<a>
<foo>
<bar>
```

I've tried several expressions with no luck. This turned out to be surprisingly harder than it seemed at first (for me anyway :P)

EDIT: Basically, anything is allowed except: `A-Z` and `a-z` between `<` and `>` characters.

Comment: "Surprisingly harder than it seemed at first" - there's a reason for that. Please see the accepted answer on [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What language? If PHP, I'd compare your string with strip_tags(your_string). The hardest part is not writing the regexp, it's writing down every single possible tag.

Answer (score 10):

If you are doing this to prevent HTML injection on a website then a much better solution is to just escape HTML special characters before sending them to the browser. Most web development environments/libraries will have a standard function to do this, for example PHP has `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` functions.

Comment: +1 I have to agree that correct escaping is better than attempting to remove dangerous text.

Comment: Yes. Attempting to remove "dangerous" stuff is the wrong approach. If you later need to store user inputs in a SQL database would you also try to strip out quotation marks? Escaping is the way to go.

Comment: I am not doing it to prevent injection, I'm doing it because a webservice we call doesn't allow (for some reason) text between two angle brackets.

Comment: @Chris Barr: Put that in your question, please!  Otherwise, it sounds like you're trying to solve a very different (and impossible) task.

Answer (score 2):

Shockingly, since you described your use case, it actually sounds like regexen will work here: you need to prevent `<SomeTextHere>` from showing up without *any* restrictions on where, and certainly no need to worry about recursion.  The following regex will do the opposite of what you want: `<[A-Za-z]+>` (changing the `+` to a `*` if you can't allow `<>`).  This *will* match everywhere such text occurs; I'd recommend putting the logic in the language instead (*e.g.*, `if (!/<[A-Za-z]+>/) { do_something() }`).  If you need it in the regex, and if your language supports such things, you can use a negative look-ahead assertion: `^(?!.*<[A-Za-z]+>)`.  This says "match at the beginning of the string (`^`) if I *can't* find (`(?!...)`) the given text—but your matched string will contain no characters.